# How do I check whether two variables overlap in the information they contain?

Tags: modeling, missing-data

I'm looking for a method to determine whether two variables contain the 'same' information. The information I'm using has different types of 'missings' or special meanings represented by specific values.

Take the following three variables for example that I would like to check whether they contain similar information:

**Number of months since last missed mortgage payment**. Has values ranging from:

- -999 (No information contained about customer having a mortgage)
- -998 (Customer has a mortgage but has not missed a mortgage payment)
- 0-72 (number of months since last mortgage payment was missed)

**Number of Missed Payments in the last twenty four months on unsecured loans**. Has values ranging from:

- -999 (No information contained about the customer having a unsecured loan)
- -998 (Customer has a unsecured loan but has not missed any payments)
- 1-24 (Customer has missed between 1 and 24 payments in the last twenty four months)

**Loan To Value** - Loan to Value for the current application. Has values ranging from e.g.50% to 150%. Will not contain missing values.

These variables (and many others) would be potential candidates to predict whether a customer will be 'bad' or 'good'.

Comment: Welcome! Can you give us a little more context? As you can imagine, there are a few different ways we could define "same" here. Why is it useful to you to know this? What do you plan to do with this information?